# Peltier-based liquid cooling system

Tags: batteries, heat, peltier, cooling, water

I-m doing a liquid-cooling project for fun, and, well powering it and cooling the hot side seems borderline impossible. I need some help.

To clarify. This is literally only to cool water, and not to cool any electronics such as PCs.

So. I want to use 6x12715 Peltier plates, which comes out to 804 W of cooling. Each Peltier is 12-15 V 15 A. How should I connect them, consecutively or in parallel? Parallel seems like a better option, but then there is another problem - that takes 90A. The only reasonably priced thing that provides that are car batteries, and these are low capacity - most of them will last 30 minutes to an hour on this thing. If you know any high-capacity batteries that can supply 12-15 V and 90 A, please specify the manufacturer and model, because I couldn't find any.

Chapter two. Cooling. At 12 V and 15 A electrical heat waste will be 180+ W thermal movement of 134 W. So I would need to cool a total of 1884 W? That's a household oven... I can use less Peltiers, yes, or I can use 12 V 3000 rpm fans to cool the casing + heat the house for free? :)

Comment: 6x180-225W requires a sturdy DC supply. I think the most cost effective supply in that area is a toroidal transformer or something similar. It's a lot of power and I think you will have trouble dissipating +1kW of heat. `heat the house for free?` <-- electricity usually isn't free :)

Comment: Why batteries when there are portable generators.

Comment: okay i've stopped on a 1200W switch power supply, thanks:). Not sure a toroidal transformer would work, wont it just fill the magnetic field and barely work?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the operating current for the Peltier device you specified is a maximum rating. Like most heating or cooling systems you likely would not require the the system to be operating at full capacity continuously. For example if you have a storage tank you might regulate the water temperature using a temperature monitor and feedback system that cycles the Peltier devices on and off to maintain a certain temperature range.

Comment: you would be better adding more fins and fans to the peltiers to maximize thermal transfer efficiency, than you would adding devices. A strong AC fan would really amplify what could be removed at what level of input power.

Answer (score 0):

> How should I connect them, consecutively or in parallel?
> You could do both depending on what your power supply is, like a 2x3 configuration. You need to account for matching because if the peltiers are not matched one could get significantly hotter and wear out faster from thermal stress.
>
> Chapter two. Cooling. At 12 V and 15 A electrical heat waste will be
> 180+ W thermal movement of 134 W. So I would need to cool a total of
> 1884 W? That's a household oven... I can use less Peltiers, yes, or I
> can use 12 V 3000 rpm fans to cool the casing + heat the house for
> free? :)

If you need 800W of cooling, you'll need a lot more than 800W to drive them. It really depends on how much heat leakage you need in the bath and how fast you need to cool it. It depends on what the resistance of the peltier (which changes with thermal gradient and varies from module to module). It also depends on how much you need to cool the water below ambient. You can calculate this from the datasheet.